# Google drive android API Demos do not work correctly

Tags: android

I have been pulling my hair out with this issue for quite awhile now. I want to upload my sqlite DB to Google drive and then also download it. The problem is that the Drive Demo I found [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) does not work. I need to get the DriveId and I do not know how, because the example application does not work. I want to `Create a file in a folder`. If there is any working tutorial, or step by step that I can use it will be greatly appreciated. I really need some help with getting this to work.

Just for clarification, this is what I want:

Can anyone tell me how to get the DriveId so that I can get the demo app to work? If this is impossible, is there any step by step tutorial that can help me to achieve uploading / downloading a file in a folder? Please let me know if you need anything

This is the `CreateFileInFolderActivity.class`:

```
public class CreateFileInFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    private DriveId mFolderDriveId;

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);
        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
                .setResultCallback(idCallback);
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
                return;
            }
            mFolderDriveId = result.getDriveId();
            Drive.DriveApi.newContents(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .setResultCallback(contentsResult);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsResult = new
            ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                return;
            }
            DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), mFolderDriveId);
            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("New file")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setStarred(true).build();
            folder.createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents())
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
        }
    };
}
```

This is the `BaseDemoActivity.class`:

```
package com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;

/**
* An abstract activity that handles authorization and connection to the Drive
* services.
*/
public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BaseDriveActivity";

    /**
     * DriveId of an existing folder to be used as a parent folder in
     * folder operations samples.
     * Existing folder ID = CAESHDBCN2RKT1FUNnYzMWlkWE5VUzJKcVNuWXdVRGcYNiCGvM3xolE= and it
     * does not work
     */
    public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "jqatpab1jsujpum14p7cq41pbtiij32q";

    /**
     * DriveId of an existing file to be used in file operation samples..
     */
    public static final String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "0ByfSjdPVs9MZTHBmMVdSeWxaNTg";

    /**
     * Extra for account name.
     */
    protected static final String EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name";

   /**
     * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
     */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;

    /**
     * Next available request code.
     */
    protected static final int NEXT_AVAILABLE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    /**
     * Google API client.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
     * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
     * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
     * activities itself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Handles resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Drive service needs to
     * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is disconnected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
     * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution is
     * available.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows a toast message.
     */
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for the {@code GoogleApiClient}.
     */
    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
      return mGoogleApiClient;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you get the EXISTING_FOLDER_ID and EXISTING_FILE_ID. I only have Client ID from OAuth 2.0 configuration...

Comment: My memory may be a bit rusty, but I think you get those when you register your app on the google drive api. @powder366

Comment: Do you have a link where you register with Drive SDK, so far I only registered to get my OAuth...

Comment: You have to register your app at https://console.developers.google.com/project?utm_referrer=http:%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fgcm%2Fgs.html, there is a Create project button once you are logged in @powder366

Comment: I did this and then in APIS & AUTH and then Credentials: OAuth, Create  new Client ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure how to get the demo app to work, but you could try creating your own folder in your app and using the DriveId from that to create a file in it.

There is an example activity for just creating a folder called CreateFolderActivity in those samples. In the result callback it returns a DriveFolderResult which you can query for the DriveID using

```
result.getDriveFolder.getDriveId();
```

Then use that DriveId when creating your file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see ListFilesInFolderActivity class, and look inside resultAdapter, where from MetaData you can retrieve the drive ID. Then there is RetrieveContentsWithProgressDialogActivity, where you can retrieve a drive id to access a File.